# How has this question been edited?

Tags: discussion, editing

[Can an infinite process be discontinuous?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92812/can-an-infinite-process-be-discontinuous)

I'm not complaining, even if it hasn't, but it says on the front page that Haxor modified it and I cannot see how.

Cheers.

Comment: Incidentally, I am a little paranoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click on the 'edited xx hours/days ago'. There, you can see the full editorial history.

That being said, at the moment of this post your question body has been edited exactly once, by yourself.

What you have probably seen in the overview is that the user wrote an answer which they themselves deleted shortly thereafter. This was seen as the last "change" in the question thread and thus was shown on the main site as last modification.

Last modification includes all of the question thread, including changes to answers.

Comment: Thank you moderator :)